# An expression to say that someone is talking without thinking

Tags: idioms, slang

What  idiom can be used define  a the situation where someone is telling something without thinking?  Possibly a slang definition.

---

Is "Don't say bullshit" a possible answer?

---

**Update**:
I fount the answer, "Cut the crap!", of course the answers below are correct too.

Comment: I hope I got the gist of it with the edit.

Comment: He stuck/put/stuffed/jammed a foot in his mouth. (I suggest this idiom for your purpose.)

He spoke out of turn.

He was leaping without looking.

He played it fast and loose.

Have a nice day.

Comment: @APrejean you can always re-open your answer and correct it. The first suggestion was a good one, you only needed to change the verb.

Comment: Except I honestly believe it is irrelevant what verb you use since the "foot in his mouth" is the idiom, so changing my post would be the equivalent to giving into terrorism for your downvote!  (Seriously, I don't believe the verb matters, and I think my idiom is the most applicable, so I will just place it here instead so that the OP can decide.) Also, I did accommodate your suggestion by providing several verbs including yours! Have a nice day.

Comment: @APrejean  Terrorism? That's not funny in the least. I would urge you to reconsider, because I previously stated the idiom is a good one, and the classic version is "I put my foot in it/my mouth" then you can suggest alternative verbs for variety's sake. Please, do not take offence where none was meant.

Comment: *Trump-like* perhaps ?

Comment: Putting mouth in motion before putting brain in gear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [**blurt**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blurt) *- to say (something) suddenly and without thinking about how people will react*

Although the Merriam-Webster definition doesn't actually mention it, *blurt **out*** is a common form.

---

OP's specific context *("You say XXX")* doesn't match any standard English expression. There are various slangy versions of *"You talk / You're talking XXX"* (where *XXX* may be *rubbish, rot, crap, [bull]shit, bollocks*, etc.). But they all focus on the idea that *what you're saying is worthless*, rather than that you're speaking without thinking.

Possibly *"You're talking **out of your ass**"* might come close to "without thinking", since to some extent it's modelled on [*"You're talking **off the top of your head**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22targeter%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22talking%20off%20the%20top%20of%20your%20head%22&tbm=bks).

Answer (score 4):

Consider the expression "say something [offhandedly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/offhand) (or *in an offhanded/offhand manner*)."

The idioms "[off the top of one's head](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+top+of+head)" and "[off the cuff](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off-the-cuff)" might also do the job for what is meant in the OP.

> [The speech was entirely off the cuff, and obviously straight from the heart.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=C7-30ji6VI0C&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=%22speech+was+entirely+off+the+cuff%22&source=bl&ots=kIDzzb12Hg&sig=Eb1Zv-ad0QyVRgshPem8t8yrcpA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=cvZaU6etBMaR0AX-8oG4Cg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22speech%20was%20entirely%20off%20the%20cuff%22&f=false)
>
> [Perhaps the things that are said off the top of one's head are truths intuited before blunt proof of the obvious is apparent.](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/371277/1/For-You)
>
> [I once said offhandedly to a coworker that had just been run over by a truck, "Wow! You look like shit!" It was meant to be disarming but it came off rather crass.](http://www.democraticunderground.com/discuss/duboard.php?az=show_mesg&forum=105&topic_id=3685401&mesg_id=3685454)

Comment: ‘Without a second thought’ is not a good fit for this, I feel. It refers to not _having to think_ about something but acting/answering instinctively and without hesitation. Talking through your hat is quite similar to talking out of your ass and means that you're talking about something without knowing the facts; it may or may not be appropriate for the meaning the asker is looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

**To cut to the quick**: [Deeply wound or distress, as in His criticism cut her to the quick. This phrase uses the quick in the sense of a vital or a very sensitive part of the body, such as under the fingernails. It also appeared in such older locutions as touched to the quick, for "deeply affected," and stung to the quick, for "wounded, distressed," both dating from the early 1500s. The current expression was considered a cliché from about 1850 on.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cut%20to%20the%20quick)

**Shoot from the hip**: [Someone who shoots from the hip talks very directly or insensitively without thinking beforehand.](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/shoot+from+the+hip.html)

Comment: That doesn't even come close to meaning ‘saying something without thinking first’.

Comment: It would seem to me that "He spoke without thinking" would be the most straightforward way of expressing the thought.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative idiom:

**[lead with one's chin](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lead-with-one%27s-chin)**

> Behave or speak incautiously:
>
> *she led with the chin and got her own way most of the time*
>
> *He led with his chin, demanding that long-term board members stand down because they were ‘too old.*
>
> *Until it can be clearly refuted, no one wants to take the chance of leading with their chin.*